# cuda sdk example bandwidthTest - build failed

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to build bandwidthTest_vs2010 from cuda sdk but I get the error: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'shrUtils32D.lib'

Additional Library Directories contains:

- $(CudaToolkitLibDir)
- ../../common/lib/$(PlatformName)
- ../../../shared/lib/$(PlatformName)

I can't find shrUtils32D.lib there.

1. What are differences between those lib directories ?
2. What should I do to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Works for me - what version of CUDA SDK etc ?

Comment: cuda toolkit 4.0.17 32 bit (May 2011), nvidia gpu computing sdk browser 4.17.516.1605, windows 7 home premium 32 bit

Comment: Did you move/rename any files/directories or change anything after installing the SDK ?

Comment: I have earlier installed Visual C++ 2008 Express. I only reinstalled Visual C++ Express (I removed two folders manually beacuse uninstaller left them on the disc: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio). And now I also can't install Parallel Nsight - I get an error message: "Installation requirements for selected features have not been met ..." but ofcourse I have installed Visual C++ 2010 Express and .NET Framework 4

Comment: It sounds like you may have messed up your various Visual Studio installations - I suggest you remove 2008, 2010 and any other versions and start again from scratch with just 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the 32 bit version of a shared utilities library they include with CUDA. For Windows Vista/7, assuming default installation, you go to:

Program Data/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0/shared

There you will see 3 shrUtils solutions, one for VS2005, one for VS2008 and another for VS2010. Open the appropriate one and select Debug and 32 bit. Hit build solution. Now your shrUtils32D.lib file will be placed in the lib/Win32 directory in that folder you navigated to.

Other people have this problem with the CUDA utilities library (cutil). The problem is solved the same way but the solution files are in:

Program Data/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0/C/common

Comment: I get errors: 1>------ Build started: Project: shrUtils, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stopwatch_win.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\stopwatch_win.cpp': No such file or directory
1>  stopwatch.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\stopwatch.cpp': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I was checking my shrUtils solution and it does not have any dependencies on stopwatch_win.cpp. If you find no other way the stopwatch_win.cpp is in Program Data/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0/C/common/src but I would suggest that you unninstall the SDK, remove any of its remaining directories and install the latest version. You have 4.0.17 and the latest is 4.0.19. Also the suggestion from Paul R in the comment to your question might be a good idea. It really sounds like you messed up your Visual Studio installations. If you start from scratch do it also for the CUDA toolkit.