# Compiling CUDA exampels with Visual Studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am trying to set up a CUDA dev env on a Windows 7 32bit computer with Visual Studio 2010 Express.

But I keep getting the following error when I try to compile the bandwithTest project that follow with the CUDA SDK!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cutil, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: shrUtils, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'lib\Win32\shrUtils32.lib'
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'lib\Win32\\cutil32.dll'
3>------ Build started: Project: bandwidthTest, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '../../bin/win32/Release//bandwidthTest.exe'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer to this question:

[cuda sdk example bandwidthTest - build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491426/cuda-sdk-example-bandwidthtest-build-failed/7497146#7497146)

If they are already built then check if they are correctly listed in the additional library directories in the solution properties, linking tab.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide: [How to Run CUDA In Visual Studio 2010](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/)